# How can I simulate download speed with System.Threading 

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Can I use System.Threading to simulate user connection speed or is there a better way or tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing in code? For instance are you using HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)  is an HTTP proxy that allows you to simulate modem speeds. (I don't know about throttling tools for TCP, much less UDP)

edit for comment:

It sets itself as the WinInet (system) proxy on startup, captures even localhost requests ([see this](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic) in case of problems); also, it can reroute requests to a different host (i.e. a request to example.com becomes a request to localhost).

Also, it has a powerful scripting engine which allows you to make custom processing rules.

Comment: does fiddler simulate localhost addresses ?

Comment: or even with a period at the end of the IP: http://127.0.0.1. <- note the final period a little out of place and it works :)

Comment: man, great everything works, but how i can make presets for speeds like DSL, 56 Modem ?

Comment: @devmania: Check http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic then - there are several ways of resolving this.

Comment: +1. Fiddler is a great tool, worth installing for any web dev work not just throttling.

Comment: @devmania: "but how i can make presets for speeds like DSL, 56 Modem?" Ask SO =D No, really, this warrants a question of its own.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ozspeedtest.com/ provides a simpler speed testing system than speedtest.net, so it should be pretty easy to run the test from C# (it just involves downloading certain sized images).

I assume you're doing something clientside.