# Simulate low speed connection on local network

Tags: sockets, networking, performance, simulate

Sometimes I want to manually test my web applications (either desktop applications calling web services or websites or RIA) to see how they behave with low speed internet connection (56 kbps for example). Is it possible to do it through network by simulating lower speed that the real one? If yes, is it also possible to simulate low quality connection (something as packet loss, connection drop, e.t.c.)?

Comment: Forgot to say: I'm talking about Windows platform. Desktop applications & RIA are written in C#. Websites can be either ASP.NET or PHP. Websites and web services are hosted on IIS7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question about speed: [How can I simulate download speed with System.Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833106/how-can-i-simulate-download-speed-with-system-threading)

What about packet loss & connection drop simulation?

Answer (score 1):

I did that with this tool http://bandwidthcontroller.com/purchaseStandard.html

They have a free trial version and a cheap full version.

Just make sure to deinstall it after your tests. Because it chokes your network even when deactivated.

So it is a really crappy tool, except for when you want a slow network.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), an HTTP debugging tool, has the option to throttle HTTP requests to emulate 56k speeds.  The speed can be adjusted with a little tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

Try [WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) which is an open source Wide Area Network emulator. You can download the image (iso, knoppix live cd) or VMWare virtual appliances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a phone line available, consider using a real modem instead of simulating it. You can just route the address you want to test through the modem and use your regular connection for all the other traffic